# Markov Sentence Generator; How to input sample text

Tags: python, generator, sentence, markov

I found a markov sentence generator for python on Github, and want to input Dr. Suess into it, but I cannot figure out how to.

On the github ( https://github.com/hrs/markov-sentence-generator ) all it says is
" $ ./sentence-generator.py filename [chain length]"
I have tried inputting this into the command line and in IDLE, and going to the location of the file, but im lost. 
note: I'm very new.

Comment: Show us your minimal code example

Answer (score 0):

from github repo [readme](https://github.com/hrs/markov-sentence-generator):

> `$ ./sentence-generator.py filename [chain length]`
>
> where filename is a file containing some training text for the
>   sentence to imitate

save your text as `filename` in the directory